# Webpage not scrolling in android mobile (HTML/CSS/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, mobile-website

My website not scrolling in android mobiles(Chrome browser) it is working in UC Browser, Safari. Perfectly working on laptop.

Help me in solving this issue

i have gone through many answers but i cant find any way out.

There is some problem in my Style.css

My Style.css

[***CLICK HERE***](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_03jP805l5qSmFYMHFCVENDVFk)

Comment: Please read [mcve].  Your link is broken, rather than providing links to code, you should include the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add media query to body

```
html, body {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* We need scroll-y */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* this is ok */
  transition: all .3s; /* most browsers understand this */
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -ms-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
}
```

overflow-y: hidden; prevents your android browser from scroling
so, you need either remove this hiddend or add meddia query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the one like below in your body,html.

```
    body 
    {
     background: #0f0f0f;
     min-height:100%; height:100%; 
     overflow:scroll; 
     display:block;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    }
```